# undefined method `build' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserName:>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Im currently working on a `Rails 4.2.6` and with `RSpec 3.7` version. When I run my test I get the following error:

```
undefined method `build' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserName:0x007ff984a99d38>
```

What is triggering this error is the following code.
require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe User, "name" do
  #setup
  it "returns the email" do
    #build
    user = build(:user, email: "everlastingwardrobe@example.com")
    # excercise and verify
    expect(user.email).to eq "everlastingwardrobe@example.com"
  end
end
```

I'm using build instead of  create because I dont want to persist data into the database. I am however using `factory_bot_rails` so I should have access to this method.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'spec_helper'
require "rspec/rails"
require "capybara/rspec"


# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  # config.before(:suite) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  # end
  #
  # config.before(:each) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  # end
  #
  # config.before(:each, js: true) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  # end
  #
  # # This block must be here, do not combine with the other `before(:each)` block.
  # # This makes it so Capybara can see the database.
  # config.before(:each) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.start
  # end
  #
  # config.after(:each) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.clean
  # end
end
```

How can I fix this issue, or should I use `create` instead?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After adding the gem

1. Create file in spec/support/factory_bot.rb
2. Add to factory_bot.rb

   `RSpec.configure do |config|
     config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
   end`
3. Add on rails_helper.rb
   `require 'support/factory_bot'`

Comment: Instead of adding `require 'support/factory_bot'` you can just uncomment this line in rails_helper.rb - `# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }` to require all the support files you have.

Answer (score 2):

The `build` method is part of `FactoryGirl` or `FactoryBot` namespace

Why don't you try

```
FactoryBot.build(:user :email => 'everlastingwardrobe@example.com')
```